# Defining a new shortcut disables unexpectedly another shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

To prevent closing Firefox and other application by a mistaken **Ctrl+Q** I added a keyboard shortcut with this combination witch opens `xclock`.

It works fine but unexpectedly the shortcut **Ctrl+A** ==> "Select all" doesn't work any more system wide.

Why the universal shortcut Ctrl+A is implicitly affected by the create of the shortcut Ctrl+Q?

How to prevent this?

Comment: Can you confirm that removing the Ctrl+Q shortcut makes Ctrl+A work again? Are you using an AZERTY keyboard?

Comment: I confirm that removing the Ctrl+Q shortcut makes Ctrl+A work again. I'm used to the AZERTY layout but since got a new laptop with QWERTY keyboard I closed many applications whenever I try to select all by AZERTY reflex. That's why I want to disable the Ctrl+Q shortcut.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a session where you never changed the keyboard layout and never hotplugged a keyboard? I've had trouble where it seemed to me that some applications had memorized shortcuts in terms of keycodes rather than keysyms as the shortcuts weren't kept on a keyboard layout change. I've never gotten to the bottom of this so I don't know exactly what was happening.

Comment: I don't remember if I changed the keyboard layout before in this setup but i came across (by testing) a solution. I created a new shortcut using the combination **Ctrl+A** and then deleted it, and the "Select All" shortcut is OK !